# Не получается создать службу виндовс

Tags: c++, winapi, service

Делаю лабораторную работу. Нужно создать программу, которая будет реализовывать со стороны сервера разные функции (создание документа, обновление документа, обновление метаданных, и т.д.), но сервер должен представлять из себя службу винды. Сам сервер уже был написан, и все, вроде, правильно работал, но когда приступил к работе со службами, произошел конфуз, служба видимо в какой-то момент виснет, после чего я не могу подключиться к серверу со стороны клиента (с помощью pipe).

Код создания сервиса:

```
    void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR argv[]){
        hService = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(ServiceName, HandlerEx, NULL);

        ssServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
        ssServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
        ssServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | 
    SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
       ssServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
       ssServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
       ssServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
       ssServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;

       SetServiceStatus(hService, &ssServiceStatus);


       while (!bServiceStopFlag)
       {
           //cout << ("Wait client\n");
           *md.DocName = { 0 };
           *md.Author = { 0 };
           *md.id = { 0 };

           DWORD  dwThreadId = 0;

           //while (true) {
           HANDLE pipe =
               CreateNamedPipeA(
                   pipename,
                   PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                   PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
                   PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
                   512,
                   512,
                   5000,
                   NULL);
           if (pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
           {
               cout << ("CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=%d.\n", GetLastError());
               return ;
           }

           if (ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL))
           {
               cout << ("Client connected\n");

               HANDLE thread;
               thread = CreateThread(
                   NULL,              // no security attribute 
                   0,                 // default stack size 
                   InstanceThread,    // thread proc
                   (LPVOID)pipe,    // thread parameter 
                   0,                 // not suspended 
                   &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID 

               if (thread == NULL)
               {
                   cout << ("CreateThread failed, GLE=%d.\n", GetLastError());
                   return ;
               }
               else CloseHandle(thread);

           }
           else
               CloseHandle(pipe);

           //}
       }
       Sleep(1000);
       ssServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
       SetServiceStatus(hService, &ssServiceStatus);}

   DWORD WINAPI HandlerEx(DWORD dwControl, DWORD dwEventType, LPVOID lpEventData, LPVOID lpContext)
{
    switch (dwControl)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
        ssServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        ssServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
        ssServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 80000;

        SetServiceStatus(hService, &ssServiceStatus);
        bServiceStopFlag = true;

        break;

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
        SetServiceStatus(hService, &ssServiceStatus);
        break;

    }

    return 1;
}
```

Я не понимаю, что именно я делаю не правильно в создании сервиса?

Comment: так отладчиком через attach наверное можно подключится и посмотреть, что не так

Comment: @PavelGridin, а как подключить его к сервису?

Comment: В студии в меню Отладка выбрать дистанционное подключение, или что то в этом духе.. далее выбрать ваш процесс и все, сервис должен быть собран в дебагер режиме.

Comment: @NewView, я не знаю почему, но у меня в отладчике не ищется сервис (SimpleService)

Comment: Заголовок вопроса и содержание расходятся. Если службу не удается создать, то этот код вообще бы не запускался. А что тут происходит - большой вопрос. Еще у вас почему-то в коде создается бесхозный поток.

Comment: @VTT, да, согласен, сглупил и не правильно написал заголовок, он скорее бы назывался "не получается создать сервер для работы с клиентом", или поправьте меня, не знаю просто как правильно следует назвать заголовок, просто службу я создаю через командную строку, если что. А и так же что вы имели в виду под "бесхозный поток"?

Comment: Ну поток создается, а дескриптор сразу закрывается без ожидания завершения этого потока.

Comment: Используйте https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 это, вставьте пошагово в процедуру загрузки и смотрите до куда что доходит и где кончается. Или `AllocConsole(); freopen("CONOUT$", "w",stdout);` но это ужасный стиль отладки :)

Comment: @NewView, спасибо! Просто никогда не использовал отладчик, да и собственно не знал как